# Azure adf copy activity for odata doesn't return all columns

Tags: azure

I am connecting to CRM online(https://CRM/XRMServices/2011/OrganizationData.svc/) using ODATA and authenticating using OAUTH however when I select any table all the columns are not returned, we have facility in Power-bi where in we can expand such columns which returns all columns, please help how we can achieve this in Data factory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I got in touch with Azure Support team and they have mentioned that this is design limitation from their side.

Comment: pls - what 'design limitation from their side" means?